# Is there a way/workaround to attach clob to a JSON element?

Tags: json, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I'm trying to add a json and add a clob to it. On the Oracle website, it says that the **`json_object_t.put`** function only supports **`varchar`**, just wondering if anyone knows a workaround?

The database version we are using is `12c`, but we might migrate to `21c`

```
declare
    j       json_object_t;
    v_clob  clob; -- > 32767 characters
begin
    j:= json_object_t;
    j.put(v_clob);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

The string length of a **`varchar2`** variable could *already* be upto **32,767** within *PL/SQL* unlike to the upper bound **4,000** which takes place in a table creation DDL statement.

So, You can convert **`v_clob  clob`** to **`v_str varchar2(32767)`** and should invoke by adding *missing* first argument(**`key`**) of type **`varchar2`** as well,conforming to a ***set procedure*** syntax:

[**`MEMBER PROCEDURE put(key VARCHAR2, value JSON_ELEMENT_T)`**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/arpls/json-types.html#GUID-10062646-E36F-48B1-9F24-751B613DFB5A)

Comment: Thanks Barbaros! 

My problem is that, the string i'm trying to attach actually is longer than 32,767 characters. 

the code below works in 21c , but not in 12c environment. the documentation for 12c and 21c only accepts varchar2 

set serveroutput on 
declare
  v_clob clob;
  j json_object_t;

begin
  select text into v_clob from tx_temp; -- length 54706 
  j:= json_object_t();
  j.put('clob',v_clob);
end;

Answer (score 1):

You should create a JSON string `'{"key_of_clob": "'`, then concat the content of the CLOB, ending by adding '"}' to obtain a CLOB containing a valid JSON expression, you could then parse it to create a JSON object:
`json_object_t.parse(my_temp_json_clob);`
and eventually you can add this one to the final JSON object using
`put(key VARCHAR2, value JSON_ELEMENT_T)`.
Don't forget to free the temporary CLOB used.

see https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9535894000346566772

Comment: Thanks! 

I will use this as a last resort.